# QT QThread::isrunning freeze program on Pi

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'm testing a programm on my PI.When running it on the host pc no error is shown, instead , running it on pi (CM3) it freezes.

I'm trying to use multithreading.

From the main thread, in the constructor an QThread is started, then when I click on the button to open a new form the GUI freezes. In the button slot I need to check if the serial_works thread has been started in the constructor has finished before opening a new form, so I added a QThread::isRunning() check;

```
Main_Form::Main_Form(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::Main_Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->move(0,0);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);         
    connect(ui->btn,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(open_form()));
    *serial_works = new SerialWorks();
    serial_works->start();
}

void Main_form::open_form(){
std::cout<<"open form slot"<<std::endl;
int i = 0;
while(serial_works->isRunning()){
    std::cout<<"WHILE"<<std::endl;
    QThread::msleep(100);
    i++;
    if(i > 10){
        serial_works->terminate();
    }
Next_form *frm = new Next_form();
this.close();
frm->show();
}
```

the run method in the Serial_works class is

```
void Serial_works::run() {
   my_function();
   this->terminate();
   this->wait();
}

void Serial_works::my_function(){
  ....stuff on serial
  std::cout<<"serial works finished"<<std::endl;
}
```

on the output i get

```
 //serial works finished
 //open_slot_form
```

no WHILE is printed out on the console,thus the program get stuck on the while check

```
serial_works->isRunning()
```

Where is the problem? On the the host pc, the new form opens as expected.

Comment: I can't answer your question but I think it would help if you listed architecture of the host, compiler and compiler and linker flags use on the Pi and the host?

Comment: you left the most important bits like *"....stuff on serial"*

Comment: I've compiled QT with ./configure -no-use-gold-linker -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v
So you can know the architecture ,and I've omitted my_function implementation because the problem is not there ,the function returns and the serial port has been closed

Comment: Linux version 4.9.58-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use QThread without understanding what is this object doing. What you want to do is **asynchronous execution** : *Do some work and when you are done let me know*.

**Edit : What is Happening** :

- Client : main thread executes `open_form` before the worker executes run
- Rasberry Pi : worker executes run before main thread executes `open_form`

On PI

1. serial_works->start() launch worker, which execute first, and complete my_function.
2. worker call `this->terminate()` and is now officially dead. [terminate is a brutal way of stopping a QThread.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate).I cannot even speculate whether wait() is called.
3. The main thread execute open_form, and the worker is already non-runnable. So the loop is not executed and Next_form is never going to be shown.

**Error 1 :**

```
Main_form::open_form()
```

is executing in the gui thread, and you are sleeping on a event. This is always incorrect. You GUI will freeze for the amout of time you are sleeping. Use signals and slots or events.

**Error 2 :**

Serial_works is likely a subclass of Qthread. You are confusing a thread of execution with the object managing that thread. ***You should not subclass QThread***.

```
   this->terminate();
   this->wait();
```

The worker thread is executing that code. You are killing ***yourself*** then waiting on your death. So depending on the implementation you may wait forever , crash, etc....

**What you need to do :**
[Use QFuture and QFutureWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html).

```
//inside Main_Form
QFutureWatcher<ReturnValueType> watcher;

void Main_form::open_form(){
    // Instantiate the objects and connect to the finished signal.
    connect(&this->watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &this, SLOT(SignalWorkFinished()));

    // Start the computation.
    QFuture<ReturnValueType> future = QtConcurrent::run(stuffOnSerialFunction);
    this->watcher.setFuture(future);
}

// now handle work finish
void SignalWorkFinished()
{
   QFuture<ReturnValueType> future = watcher.future();
   //do whatever you like
}
```

Comment: But on the host pc the code works ,I'm sorry but why am I sleeping on an event ?After a QThread::msleep(100) I check if the second thread has finished and in that case the code continues until the frm->show();

Comment: And why no "WHILE" is printed out?

Comment: Ok i I've understood ,but how is it possible that on the host the form opens?Why it freezes on the Pi and not on the host?